# How to deal with inserting data from multiple tables?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a table named canvaslocal with fields : canvasID,cnamebonds(char 100),cnamedebs(char 100),cnameshares(char 100). I've to insert  data into this table. The reference tables are
t_bondridapp : debID(ID),debissuedate(DATETIME),cancode(INT),canname(CHAR 45)
t_debtrfapp: recNO(ID),debissuedate(DATETIME),cancode(INT),canname(CHAR 45)
share_application: id(ID),debissuedate(DATETIME),cancode(INT),canname(CHAR 45)

I have a dropdownlist in my form which selects name and two textboxes which selects starting and ending dates.

I have to add t_bondridapp.canname to cnamebonds,t_debtrfapp.canname to cnamedebs and share_application.canname to cnameshares where the canname must be equal to dropdownlistvalue and the date must be between the to textboxes dates.
I've used a code :

```
    string name=Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
    DateTime fdate=DateTime.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    DateTime sdate=dateTime.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
    var dbcon = DBConnection.Instance();
    dbcon.DBName="pnys";
    if(dbcon.IsConnect())
    {
       string q1=@"INSERT INTO canvaslocal (cnamebonds) SELECT          t_bondridapp.canname FROM t_bondridapp WHERE (debissuedate >= @fdate AND debissuedate <= @sdate) AND canname =@name";
       string q2=@"INSERT INTO canvaslocal (cnamedebs) SELECT          t_debtrfapp.canname FROM t_debtrfapp WHERE (debissuedate >= @fdate AND debissuedate <= @sdate) AND canname =@name";
       string q3=@"INSERT INTO canvaslocal (cnameshares) SELECT          share_application.canname FROM share_application WHERE (debissuedate >= @fdate AND debissuedate <= @sdate) AND canname =@name";

       using(var command = new MySqlCommand(q1,dbcon.Connection))
       {
         command.Parameters.Add("@name",MySqlDbType.String).Value =name;
         command.Parameters.Add("@fdate",MySqldbType.DateTime).value =fdate;       
         command.Parameters.Add("@sdate",MySqldbType.DateTime).value =sdate;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }

       using(var command = new MySqlCommand(q2,dbcon.Connection))
       {
         command.Parameters.Add("@name",MySqlDbType.String).Value =name;
         command.Parameters.Add("@fdate",MySqldbType.DateTime).value =fdate;       
         command.Parameters.Add("@sdate",MySqldbType.DateTime).value =sdate;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }

       using(var command = new MySqlCommand(q3,dbcon.Connection))
       {
         command.Parameters.Add("@name",MySqlDbType.String).Value =name;
         command.Parameters.Add("@fdate",MySqldbType.DateTime).value =fdate;       
         command.Parameters.Add("@sdate",MySqldbType.DateTime).value =sdate;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
   }
```

Is there any other simple queries to pass these values more effectively? And also I've kept the fields cnamebonds, cnamedebs AND cnameshares AS they can hold NULL values. 
Please help me.

Comment: As I can see, then at the moment you will end up with 3 records in canvaslocal  which look like record 1:  <id>, t_bondridapp.canname, null, null  record 2:  <id>, null, t_bondridapp.cnamedebs, null record 3: <id>, null, null, t_bondridapp.cnameshares.  Is this what you want?

Comment: As a general comment, when issuing multiple statements that change the data, then you should wrap them in a single transaction.  Otherwise you could end up with data inconsistency where some statements work and others didn't.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Sir,actully I wants to calculate the no of items canvased by each person. So I thought that adding the rows with their names and COUNT it. Is there any other idea..?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see enough information to be able to comment on your business logic/flow so that's difficult for me to comment.  It is possible to insert the data into a single row, if you prefer this, but if you want 3 rows then this looks OK with me apart from the transaction issue I mentioned above.